# Конфликт в коде PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

Добрый день! Столкнулся со странной проблемой, а именно:

Функция `query_to_google` прекрасно работает сама по себе в отдельном документе, но когда я начинаю ее внедрять в основной модуль массив `$a` обнуляется сам собой.

Под обнуляется, подразумеваю, что до добавления проблемной строки  `print_r ($a)` выдает `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 5 )` После добавления проблемной строки, `print_r ($a)` выдает `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )`

До строки где объявляется массив `$material_name_array` находится фрагмент кода основного модуля.
Конфликт заключается в том, что после добавления строки

```
 $pExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($uploadPath);
```

массив `$a` обнуляется и у меня не выполняется вложенный  `foreach`, который предназначен для обработки ссылки.

Пока этой строки нет, код работает отлично.

Прошу, подскажите с чем это может быть связано? В php неопытен.

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Каталог, в который мы будем принимать файл:
$uploaddir = 'uploadFile/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);



// Копируем файл из каталога для временного хранения файлов:
if (copy($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
    {
    echo "<h3>Файл успешно загружен на сервер</h3>";
    //header( 'Refresh: 0; url=../formsComplete.php' );
    }
else {
    echo "<h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</h3>"; 
    // header( 'Refresh: 0; url=../formsError.php' );

    }



$uploadPath = 'uploadFile/';
$fileName = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$uploadPath .= $fileName;

$pExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($uploadPath);

// выбираем лист, с которым будем работать
$pExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$aSheet = $pExcel->getActiveSheet(0);

// Цикл по листам Excel-файла
foreach ($pExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    // выгружаем данные из объекта в массив
    $tables[] = $worksheet->toArray();
}

// тут огромный кусок кода обработки Excel файла
// Результатом его работы будет массив $material_name_array

$material_name_array = array("Муфта+соединительная+GUSJ-12/150-240+(E08773-064)+купить");

function query_to_google($material_name_array) {

        foreach ($material_name_array as $query_string) {

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $dom = new DomDocument;
        $dom->loadHTMLFile("https://www.google.ru/search?q=".$query_string);

        $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
        $a = $xpath->query('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@href');

        print_r ($a); 

           foreach ($a as $b){

            $extract_href = ""; //Переменная в которой будет храниться итоговая обработанная ссылка
            $href_buffer = ""; // Буфер для отсечения куска в начале строки
            $href_buffer2 = ""; // Буфер для отсечения куска в конце строки

            $extract_href = $b->textContent.PHP_EOL;

             echo "<br>Необработанная строка: ", $extract_href,"<br>";

            $href_buffer = explode("/url?q=", $extract_href); 

            $href_buffer2 = $href_buffer[1]; 

            $href_buffer2 = explode("&sa=U&ved", $href_buffer2);

            $extract_href = $href_buffer2[0];

            echo $extract_href;

            echo "</br></br>#######################</br>";

            }

        $freeze_time = rand(3,5);

        sleep($freeze_time);

       }

  }

//~~~~~тело~~~~~

query_to_google ($material_name_array);
```

Comment: Что значит "обнуляется"? Опишите симптоматику по шагам, чтобы не приходилось подключать телепатию

Comment: И загляните в лог ошибок, который на сервере находится.

Comment: до того как в коде присутствует проблемная строка, print_r ($a) выдает
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 5 )
После добавления проблемной строки, print_r ($a) выдает
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )

Это главное, что мешает и это я подразумевал под словом "обнуляется". Приношу извинения за неточную терминологию.

Comment: Visman, к сожалению в логе ничего по этому поводу не говорится - все проходит штатно

Comment: Проверьте кроме $a еще и $material_name_array.

Comment: До добавления проблемной строки print_r ($material_name_array);  выдает Array ( [0] => Муфта+соединительная+GUSJ-12/150-240+(E08773-064)+купить )  , а после добавления Array ( [0] => Муфта+соединительная+GUSJ-12/150-240+(E08773-064)+купить )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте пути:

```
$uploaddir = __DIR__.'/uploadFile';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . "/" . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
```

---

```
$uploadPath = __DIR__.'/uploadFile/';
$fileName = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$uploadPath .= $fileName;
```

И замените **loadHTMLFile** на **CURL**:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.google.ru/search?q=".$query_string);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DomDocument;
$suc = $dom->loadHTML($cl);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$a = $xpath->query('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/div/h3/a/@href');
```